# If I just need a webview, is PhoneGap too much?

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I'm working on an online multiplayer mobile web app that runs 100% in the browser from a Meteor server (a demo for to me learn new techniques). This is basically just a single page html5 app card game with touch/drag events.

All I would really need is a web view to remove the address bar and nav bar, would PhoneGap be overkill for this purpose? (i've never used mobile web views or PhoneGap before). I would be targeting mainly iOS and Android.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is too much. Apple reserves the right and most likely will not approve your app if it is just an app hosting a webview.

iOS web apps: https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_iPhoneWebApp/_index.html

Android web apps:
http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/overview.html

Comment: To further add to this, Apple requires that the app *provides functionality even when there is no active network connection*. Which expressedly forbids just having a UIWebView requesting a page from an external server then; as of course the app will fail when there's no network connection - most likely displaying some form of HTTP error.

Comment: Oh yea good points. What if it had enough functionality to have a login screen, or click anonymous and then once either are clicked, it takes you to the web view (which looks like an app)? Sort of like you can't use the facebook app unless you log in. I'll definitely have to look into this further. Thanks!!!